# c# connect to sql via jdbc

Tags: java, c#, sql, jdbc, jni4net

I have a program in c# and need to connect to SQL via JDBC. I read that JDBC works with java and since I need to use it from C#, I found out that there is jni4net that bridges between the two.

I can't seem to find any samples or tutorials on how to do so. Any help will be appreciated. I have read and tried using jni4net, but I couldn't find any sample connecting to a database.

Comment: What did you think the `J` stood for in JDBC?

Comment: "i have a program in c# and need to connet to sql via jdbc" - erm , why?

Comment: @MitchWheat you asked why? short answer to your question is that the company closed access via OLE and moved over to JDBC. - even though our program is in c#

Comment: what about sql native client? what's wrong with that?

Comment: @MitchWheat we are third company and the client buys our product. the client uses MF and closed all connections other than jdbc. we have to migrate our connection only to that specific cient

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "the client uses MF". JDBC is an API, it says nothing about the protocol used by the actual driver implementing that API. An equivalent ADO.net provider would likely use the same network protocol and would be indistinguishable from a JDBC driver implementing that same protocol. If your client demands Java applications, then you might just be out of luck.

Answer (score 4):

JDBC stands for Java DataBase Connectivity, which means it is for Java (or other languages that can run on the Java Virtual Machine). C# is a different language with its own runtime. Although it may be possible to access Java from C#, doing so for database connections would probably be really cumbersome and slow.

Instead you should look for an ADO.net database provider for your database system(s). Most database systems have one.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the robbiblubber.org JDBC Extension Libaray to connect to a database via JDBC from .NET. Of cource, if there is a native driver for ADO.NET, you should use that.